# Spring Data JPA - Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, h2

I am trying out Spring Data. I have a very basic application. 
Parts :
1. Main application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

2. Then I have my POM.XML

   https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       4.0.0
       
           org.springframework.boot
           spring-boot-starter-parent
           2.1.13.RELEASE
            
       
       com.italktocomputer.spring-boot-microservices
       currency-exchange-service
       0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
       currency-exchange-service
       Demo project for Spring Boot

   ```
   <properties>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
       <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
           <scope>runtime</scope>
           <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
           <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
           <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
               <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
               <type>pom</type>
               <scope>import</scope>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```

The application runs fine but when I add the data.sql file:

```
insert into exchange_value (id,currencyFrom, currencyTo, exchangeRate) values (10000,'USD','CAD',1);
```

I get the following error :

```
2020-03-08 15:42:39.836  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2020-03-08 15:42:39.869  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=currency-exchange-service, profiles=[default], label=null, version=eaf703d5fc6fba5debfc8a23c08c6ec936082d16, state=null
2020-03-08 15:42:39.869  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configClient'}]
2020-03-08 15:42:39.870  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] i.s.c.CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-08 15:42:40.089  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-08 15:42:40.091  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-03-08 15:42:40.118  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=3ba16513-849a-3407-8710-797184dfd4c9
2020-03-08 15:42:40.191  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8000 (http)
2020-03-08 15:42:40.192  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-03-08 15:42:40.192  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-03-08 15:42:40.198  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat-22].[localhost].[/]    : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-03-08 15:42:40.198  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 327 ms
2020-03-08 15:42:40.349  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-34 - Starting...
2020-03-08 15:42:40.350  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-34 - Start completed.
2020-03-08 15:42:40.355  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2020-03-08 15:42:40.359  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Hibernate: drop table exchange_curreny if exists
Hibernate: create table exchange_curreny (id integer not null, currency_from varchar(255), currency_to varchar(255), exchange_rate decimal(19,2), primary key (id))
2020-03-08 15:42:40.746  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@65386fb9'
2020-03-08 15:42:40.746  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-08 15:42:40.753  WARN 7053 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : Unable to start LiveReload server
2020-03-08 15:42:40.755  WARN 7053 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Users/nikku/Downloads/currency-exchange-service/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into exchange_value (id,currencyFrom, currencyTo, exchangeRate) values (10000,'USD','CAD',1); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "EXCHANGE_VALUE" not found; SQL statement:
insert into exchange_value (id,currencyFrom, currencyTo, exchangeRate) values (10000,'USD','CAD',1) [42102-200]
2020-03-08 15:42:40.959  WARN 7053 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-200]
2020-03-08 15:42:40.959  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-34 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-03-08 15:42:40.963  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-34 - Shutdown completed.
2020-03-08 15:42:40.963  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-03-08 15:42:40.970  INFO 7053 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-08 15:42:40.971 ERROR 7053 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Users/nikku/Downloads/currency-exchange-service/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into exchange_value (id,currencyFrom, currencyTo, exchangeRate) values (10000,'USD','CAD',1); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "EXCHANGE_VALUE" not found; SQL statement:
insert into exchange_value (id,currencyFrom, currencyTo, exchangeRate) values (10000,'USD','CAD',1) [42102-200]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at com.italktocomputer.springbootmicroservices.currencyexchangeservice.CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication.main(CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Users/nikku/Downloads/currency-exchange-service/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into exchange_value (id,currencyFrom, currencyTo, exchangeRate) values (10000,'USD','CAD',1); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "EXCHANGE_VALUE" not found; SQL statement:
insert into exchange_value (id,currencyFrom, currencyTo, exchangeRate) values (10000,'USD','CAD',1) [42102-200]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:509) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:239) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:49) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:202) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:119) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:89) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:37) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:402) ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359) ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:99) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:90) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:429) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1775) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "EXCHANGE_VALUE" not found; SQL statement:
insert into exchange_value (id,currencyFrom, currencyTo, exchangeRate) values (10000,'USD','CAD',1) [42102-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7628) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7599) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1747) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:954) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:212) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:488) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Application.Properties

```
spring.application.name = currency-exchange-service
server.port = 8000

spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.h2.console.enabled = true
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
public class ExchangeCurreny {

    ExchangeCurreny() {

    }

    public ExchangeCurreny(int id, String currencyFrom, String currencyTo, BigDecimal exchangeRate) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.currencyFrom = currencyFrom;
        this.currencyTo = currencyTo;
        this.exchangeRate = exchangeRate;
    }
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String currencyFrom, currencyTo;
    private BigDecimal exchangeRate;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCurrencyFrom() {
        return currencyFrom;
    }
    public void setCurrencyFrom(String currencyFrom) {
        this.currencyFrom = currencyFrom;
    }
    public String getCurrencyTo() {
        return currencyTo;
    }
    public void setCurrencyTo(String currencyTo) {
        this.currencyTo = currencyTo;
    }
    public BigDecimal getExchangeRate() {
        return exchangeRate;
    }
    public void setExchangeRate(BigDecimal exchangeRate) {
        this.exchangeRate = exchangeRate;
    }
}
```

I have no idea what is going on. Appreciate your guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: share application.properties and exchange_value table entity

Comment: Look at the error message : `Table "EXCHANGE_VALUE" not found`. You are inserting into a table which does not exist

Comment: I have shaed my application.properties. I read a couple of answers. They said that you get that error message when your connection is already closed.

Comment: @dassum Shared the entity class.

Comment: Simply make sure your table(s) exist before running the insert script, or active `ddl-auto`, or include create statements in your script.

Comment: @Yann39 How to ensure table exists without script? The tutorial I am following does not have create statement in the script.

Comment: You can activate Hibernate auto DDL as you are using Spring data JPA. It can automatically validate/create/update/drop the database schema when the SessionFactory is created. Simply set the property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to one of the possible values, basically use `update` which will update your schema on any change to your entities. There are some limitations and it is not really recommended in production (but not a drama if you know what you are doing. I personaly use it in production for years without any problem). See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the nested exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "EXCHANGE_VALUE" not found; SQL statement:
```

It means either that the table doesn't exist or at least it can't be found.
I assume EXCHANGE_VALUE is actually the name of the table in the database (double check for spelling errors).

You could also check how you named your Entity in Java and try to explicitly declaring table name with annotation @Table.

```
@Table(name = "exchange_value")
public class ExchangeValue {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, but my mistake was to put the entities into a different package from the @SpringBootApplication class.

My main class was in "com.example.test" and my entities were in package "com.example.test2.domain".

When I put my entities into "com.example.test.domain" everything got back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql

1. Use Schema.sql and data.sql to create and insert data
2. Here is the syntax
3. `create table exchange_value (id bigint not null, fromvalue varchar(255), multiplication_factor double not null, to varchar(255), primary key (id));` -> Schema.sql
4. `insert into exchange_value (id,fromvalue,multiplication_factor,to) values (1,'USD',889,'INR');` --> data.sql
5. add `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` in your application.config
6. **It's also important to remember to turn off automatic schema creation to avoid conflicts**: this is the line that gave me the answer

`

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue and by using **schema.sql** along with **data.sql** file with respective sql script and following entry into **application.properties** file, It was resolved by following :

**application.properties**

```
# h2 database Configuration
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password = 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

**schema.sql**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EXCHANGE_VALUE;  
CREATE TABLE EXCHANGE_VALUE (  
id INT PRIMARY KEY,  
currency_from VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,  
currency_to VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,  
conversion_multiple INT(8) NOT NULL,
port INT(5)
);
```

**data.sql**

```
insert into exchange_value(id,currency_from,currency_to,conversion_multiple,port)
    values(1001,'USD','INR',75,0);
insert into exchange_value(id,currency_from,currency_to,conversion_multiple,port)
    values(1002,'SAR','INR',20,0);
insert into exchange_value(id,currency_from,currency_to,conversion_multiple,port)
    values(1003,'EUR','INR',87,0);
```